# Javascript to search for keyword in body text and if found, redirect to specific URL

Tags: javascript, search, redirect

I am trying to use JavaScript to search for a specific keyword in the body text of a page.

If the keyword appears in the body text, I then need the page to immediately be redirected to a specified URL. If the keyword does not appear in the body text, nothing happens.

I tried something like this:

```
function redirect() {
var thing = $('body:contains("keyword")').text();
   if(thing) {
    window.location.replace("http://websiteurlhere");
   }
}
```

Needless to say, I haven't have much luck.  It's a strange request, but if anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your function where you need it and use `.attr()` to redirect if the keyword is found

```
function redirect() {
var thing = $('p:contains("keyword")').text();
   if(thing) {
       $(location).attr('href',"http://websiteurlhere");//JQuery redirect
   }
}
redirect();//Call your function
```

If you absolutely want to redirect with JavaScript and not with Jquery, you can use this (instead of `.attr()`):

```
document.location.href="http://websiteurlhere";
```

Comment: This worked great.  The only adjustment that I seem to have to make was to use $('p:contains("keyword")') - (as the text I was wanting to search was between <p></p> tags), instead of using $('body:contains("keyword")').  Using $('body:contains("keyword")') did not return a result, but when I narrowed it down to $('p:contains("keyword")'), it worked perfectly.  Any idea why this would be?

Comment: @Vivi_555 I've updated my answer with `$('p:contains("keyword")')`>. I can't tell you why without your HTML. Can you click on the tick to put the question as resolved please?